# APPJAR PYTHON creating an grid of entry boxes which varies depending on user input

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops, widget

I'm creating a lottery program and I'm trying to create a table of ticket for the ticket page where the user will enter their numbers with Z being 5 numbers on a ticket and Y being 5 different tickets but I can't figure out how to change the entry title as title needs to be in "ticketYZ" but YZ won't change values since its in quotation marks.

```
from appJar import gui

app = gui("grid", "700x700")
app.setBg("palegreen")

for Y in range(0, 5):
    for Z in range(0, 5):
        app.addEntry(ticketYZ, Y, Z)

app.go()
```

Answer (score 0):

The name for each entry needs to be provided as a string.

You could try concatenating the Y and Z values onto the end of the word **ticket**:

`app.addEntry('ticket'+str(Y)+str(Z), Y, Z)`